# How to install glibc 2.12 or 2.14 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: 12.04, java, glibc

I am making a JNI call to a C++ library and it is compiled in `glibc` v2.12 or v2.14, but Ubuntu 12.04 has `glibc 2.15`.

Whenever I make a call to the C++ library I get the error `glibc 2.14 not found`. How do I go about installing `glibc` 2.12/2.14?

Comment: I was under the impression that glibc is backward-compatible, so running an application compiled on glibc 2.14 should be possible on glibc 2.15.

Comment: I thought so too, cause that is what i have read. But for some reason it is just not working.